# Clicking outside the responsive menu doesn't close the nav bar properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to close the nav bar if i click outside of it .

The first time works fine but after that it doesn't.

I don't know where or how should i use the 'mouseup' event listener in order to get the result i want.

Here is my code : https://codepen.io/bunea-andrei/pen/jOBGNgd?editors=1100 . It's a mobile version .

Also the JavaScript code here :

```js
burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
            wrapper.classList.toggle("wrapper-active");


            window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
                if (event.target != wrapper && event.target != burger && event.target.parentNode != burger && event.target.parentNode != wrapper) {
                    wrapper.classList.remove("wrapper-active");
                    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
                }
            });


            //Animate Links
            wrapperLinks.forEach((link, index) => {

                if (link.style.animation) {   //if the animantion took place do nothing else do it
                    link.style.animation = "";
                } else {

                    link.style.animation = `wrapperLinkFade  0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.2}s`;
                }
            });


            //Burger Animation
            burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
        });

    }


wrapperSlide();
```

Any help is welcome . Thank you

Comment: i think this css is causing problem @media only screen and (max-width: 540px)
.wrapper span {
     opacity: 0; 
}

Comment: wrapperLinks.forEach((link, index) => {...}   this function doesn't get executed the second time , only the third time , there is a problem with the logic i'm using

Comment: it is executing everytime. i put a console.log inside it

Comment: i know but the way i'm executing the functions is not correct , after you close the nav bar once by clicking outside , every click outside is toggling the burger lines

Comment: can you try this window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
                if (event.target != wrapper && event.target != burger && event.target.parentNode != burger && event.target.parentNode != wrapper) {
                    wrapper.classList.remove("wrapper-active");
 console.log(2);                   burger.classList.remove("toggle");
                }
            });

Comment: i need to don't execute that function if the burger is closed but i don't know how

Comment: add this condition && burger.classList.contains('toggle') in if

Comment: thank you man , it does the job . the function with the animations still doesn't get executed but i removed it and it's all good . thank you so much